# Looping through Collection of Dictionaries

Tags: vba, loops, dictionary, collections

I have created a collection of dictionaries and have NO idea how to loop through them all.

The collection consists of the various types of animals that a farm may have:

- Cows
- Dogs
- Swans

Each of these are dictionaries containing more details on the types of animals within that group:

- Cows (Spotted, White, White, Black)
- Dogs (Big, Middle, Middle, Small)
- Swans (Cream, Dark)

I am trying to have an overview of my dataset - to see which 'unique' types of Cows, Dogs and Swans I have.

To do this, I was thinking of first looping through the collection of animals, and then go into each dictionary to screen through the list and extract the unique values.

Easier said than done :P

Here's what I have so far... and it's getting me nowhere:

```
Dim Cows, Dogs, Swans as Object

Set Cows = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set Dogs = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set Swans = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
```

[...Add all the farm data into the 3 categories above...]

```
Dim TotalAnimals As New Collection, AnimalType
    TotalAnimals.Add Cows
    TotalAnimals.Add Dogs
    TotalAnimals.Add Swans

    For Each AnimalType In TotalAnimals
       
        For Each Animal In AnimalType <<< HERE lies my error
        
        [Code for selecting unique values, works perfectly]

        Next Animal

    Next Animaltype
```

Any ideas on how to solve this (fairly simple) question?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/keys-method

Comment: Thank you KL but the key itself is a dictionary. Does this make sense? I need to loop each dictionary within the collection.

Comment: The .keys method only works with dictionaries, not with collections unfortunately.

As a result, I am struggling to tell Excel to A) take the full collection (cows, dogs, swans) and then B) for each dictionary inside the collection execute the code.

My objective is to keep the dictionaries separate and be able to identify the unique values in each of them without 'merging' everything into one list. This is why I need separate dictionaries and cannot simply make one dictionary that I loop through using the code in your link.

Hope this explains it better!

Comment: You do a `For - Each` loop on the collection. For each element, a dictionary, you make an array of the values. Then do a `For Each` loop on the array looking up the value in the dictionary with the key.

Comment: Hey again, that is what I am trying to do in the code above. However, it is not working. I suspect it is because I have not defined Animal. Tried adding it in the Dim of each dictionary (with a comma at the end) but the code doesn’t like having it defined 3x.

Comment: I don't know what more I could say.

Comment: No problem, thank you in any case!

Comment: Well, the only error in the line `For Each Animal In AnimalType <<< HERE lies my error` is the obvious lack of `'` where comment starts.  The above code isn't throwing any error. `Debug.Print TypeName(Animal)`  gives value as `Empty' which is fine because they are empty.